# pdf and epub notes , bookmarks and highlights feature

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to develop iPhone application which allow user to create note on particular text ,user can bookmark page and save highlighted text. How can I do that . I know about PSPDFKit but it is no free any one knows about any free resource for that ? or another way I can do this .

I have highlighted text of pdf and epub file but how can I save that highlighted text and how to bookmark pages ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

using core-text to render the text. and check the EGOTextView as example for highlight.

Comment: I am able to highlight text but I want to save all highlights and notes and bookmark for pdf and epubs. If you have seen kindle app you can get some idea what I want

Comment: I think you need to find these info and save to core-data or disk.